# Upload video to AWS S3 in .net

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3, .net-core

So im trying to upload a video to my S3 bucket, the code almost works, what it currently does is upload an empty file to the bucket, so the API is interacting correctly with AWS but it's not sending the video in the request. When I send up an image (and change the '.mp4' to '.png') it works perfectly but when I upload a video, it doesn't work

Controller

```
    [HttpPost("{userId}/video")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(999_000_000)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> VideoUpload(int userId, [FromForm] PhotoForCreationDto photoForCreationDto)
    {
       AmazonS3VideoUploader amazonS3v = new AmazonS3VideoUploader();

        var keyName = photoForCreationDto.Username + getKeyName() + ".mp4";

        var file = photoForCreationDto.File;

        amazonS3v.UploadFile(file, keyName);

        return Ok();
    }
```

Repository

```
    public async void UploadFile(IFormFile file, string keyName)
    {
        var client = new AmazonS3Client(myAwsAccesskey, myAwsSecret, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);

        using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            try
            {
                PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = keyName,
                    InputStream = stream,
                    // ContentType = "image/png"
                    ContentType = "video/mp4"
                };

                PutObjectResponse response = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);

            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
            {
                if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                    (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
                    ||
                    amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error occurred: " + amazonS3Exception.Message);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

After a while it gives me this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
   at System.IO.FileStream.get_Position()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.get_Position()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.ReferenceReadStream.VerifyPosition()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.ReferenceReadStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 149
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at cartalk.api.Data.AmazonS3VideoUploader.UploadFile(IFormFile file, String keyName) in D:\Projects in progress\Car talk\_application - current\cartalk.api\Data\AmazonS3VideoUploader.cs:line 82
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error I had to change the code around a bit, instead of sending the video (System.IO.Stream) to the repository, I had to do everything inside of the controller itself. I think that the reason this happened is because the stream closed before the request was sent to AWS. Read more about it here: [System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210999/system-objectdisposedexception-cannot-access-a-closed-stream)

This is what I changed it to:

```
[HttpPost("{userId}/video")]
[RequestSizeLimit(999_000_000)]
public async Task<ActionResult> VideoUpload(int userId, [FromForm] PhotoForCreationDto photoForCreationDto)
        {

        AmazonS3VideoUploader amazonS3v = new AmazonS3VideoUploader();

        var keyName = getKeyName() + ".mp4";

        var file = photoForCreationDto.File;

        var client = new AmazonS3Client(myAwsAccesskey, myAwsSecret, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);

        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName,
                        Key = keyName,
                        InputStream = stream,
                        ContentType = "video/mp4"
                    };

                    await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);

                }
                catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
                {
                    if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                        (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
                        ||
                        amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Error occurred: " + amazonS3Exception.Message);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```