# File upload asp.net core - System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed file.'

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am using asp.net core and programming in C#.

I have a method in a controller to upload a file from a form in a view.

```
public async void UploadFile([FromForm(Name = "aFile")] IformFile aFile)
{
   var filePath = Path.Combine(_webhost.WebRootPath, "Images", aFile.FileName);

   if (aFile.Length > 0)
   {
      using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
      {
         await aFile.CopyToAsync(fs);
      }
   }
}
```

A 155kb uploaded successfully; however, a 3.38 MB file failed:

`System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed file.'`

I have read that the issue may pertain to limits and stream disposal; however, the problem persists despite adding fixes I've seen recommended on stack overflow such as:

`[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit, RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue, ValueLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue, ValueCountLimit = Int32.MaxValue)]`

Any recommendations would be welcome :) thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your running into a race condition due to your usage of `async void`. Due to the `void` return type, the server code running your app can not know when your method finishes and disposes the request immediately.
Use `Task` as the return type of your `UploadFile` method.

You should generally avoid `void` return types when working with `async`.
[See the article from Microsoft for more infos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void)

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix is documented in this thread: https://forums.asp.net/t/1397944.aspx?+Cannot+access+a+closed+file.

Specifically, changing the value of 'requestLengthDiskThreshold' in your web config.

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="20000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"/>
</system.web>
```

A similar fix is mentioned @ [System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210999/system-objectdisposedexception-cannot-access-a-closed-stream)

Comment: Thank you for your advice Jeremy. I have added a web.config file to my project and changed the 'requestLengthDiskThreshold' as above. No luck :(

Comment: Can this implemented on net core?